# URL substitution using vectors

Tags: r

I'm trying to substitute the years 2000-2020 into the url by using vectors. The error I get is  Can't combine `1$Rnk`  and `4$Rnk` . How can I fix this?

```
TDF_wtables <- function(url){
  url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    # extract the table part of the html code
    html_node("table") %>%
    # create R dataset from webpage contents
    html_table() %>%
    # only Year and Gross are of interest in our analysis
    select(c("Rnk", "Rider", "Team", "Time")) %>%
    as_tibble()
}
Year <- 2000:2020
TDFurls <- str_c("https://www.procyclingstats.com/race/tour-de-france/",Year,"/gc")
Maps <- map_dfr(TDFurls, TDF_wtables, .id = "Year")
Maps
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because sometimes there are rows like this

[image]

For any table that contains rows like the one shown above, the program cannot naturally tell if the `Rnk` column should be of a `character` type or an `integer` type. The simplest solution to this would be just converting all everything into `character`

```
TDF_wtables <- function(url){
  url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    # extract the table part of the html code
    html_node("table") %>%
    # create R dataset from webpage contents
    html_table() %>%
    # only Year and Gross are of interest in our analysis
    select(c("Rnk", "Rider", "Team", "Time")) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    # all columns as character
    mutate(across(.fns = as.character))
}
```

Output

```
> Maps <- map_dfr(TDFurls, TDF_wtables)
> Maps
# A tibble: 3,225 x 4
   Rnk   Rider                                      Team                      Time          
   <chr> <chr>                                      <chr>                     <chr>         
 1 1     Zanini StefanoMapei - Quickstep            Mapei - Quickstep         3:12:363:12:36
 2 2     Zabel ErikTeam Telekom                     Team Telekom              ,,0:00        
 3 3     Vainšteins RomānsVini Caldirola - Sidermec Vini Caldirola - Sidermec ,,0:00        
 4 4     Rodriguez FredMapei - Quickstep            Mapei - Quickstep         ,,0:00        
 5 5     van Heeswijk MaxMapei - Quickstep          Mapei - Quickstep         ,,0:00        
 6 6     Magnien EmmanuelLa Française des Jeux      La Française des Jeux     ,,0:00        
 7 7     Simon FrançoisBonjour - Toupargel          Bonjour - Toupargel       ,,0:00        
 8 8     McEwen RobbieFarm Frites                   Farm Frites               ,,0:00        
 9 9     Commesso SalvatoreSaeco                    Saeco                     ,,0:00        
10 10    Piziks ArvisMemoryCard - Jack & Jones      MemoryCard - Jack & Jones ,,0:00        
# ... with 3,215 more rows
```

**Update**

That Time column has two `span`s nested in each row. They have the same text, so you have to trim off one of them to avoid repetition. Also, I just realised that your code does not get you the table you want. You only want the table on the "GC" tab, right? Consider the following function:

```
TDF_wtables <- function(url){
  gc_table <- 
    url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_node("div[class$='resultCont '] > table")
  
  timeff <- 
    gc_table %>% 
    html_nodes("tbody > tr > td > span.timeff") %>% 
    html_text()
  
  gc_table %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    select(c("Rnk", "Rider", "Team", "Time")) %>%
    as_tibble() %>% 
    mutate(Time = timeff, across(.fns = as.character))
}
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3,222 x 4
   Rnk   Rider                                 Team                 Time       
   <chr> <chr>                                 <chr>                <chr>      
 1 NA    Armstrong LanceUS Postal Service      US Postal Service    " 92:33:08"
 2 2     Ullrich JanTeam Telekom               Team Telekom         "6:02"     
 3 3     Beloki JosebaFestina - Lotus          Festina - Lotus      "10:04"    
 4 4     Moreau ChristopheFestina - Lotus      Festina - Lotus      "10:34"    
 5 5     Heras RobertoKelme - Costa Blanca     Kelme - Costa Blanca "11:50"    
 6 6     Virenque RichardPolti                 Polti                "13:26"    
 7 7     Botero SantiagoKelme - Costa Blanca   Kelme - Costa Blanca "14:18"    
 8 8     Escartín FernandoKelme - Costa Blanca Kelme - Costa Blanca "17:21"    
 9 9     Mancebo FranciscoBanesto              Banesto              "18:09"    
10 10    Nardello DanieleMapei - Quickstep     Mapei - Quickstep    "18:25"    
# ... with 3,212 more rows
```

Comment: thank you this is great. Any tips on how to get the time variables to not show up doubled?